# $apply not working in OData v4 Northwind API

Tags: odata

While trying to access the above odatav4 link with $apply query it shows an error as

"The query parameter '$apply' begins with a system-reserved '$' character but is not recognized."

but works if (apply) used instead of ("$apply")

https://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products/?$apply=groupby((UnitsInStock))&$count=true&$top=1000

[service link](https://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products/?$apply=groupby((UnitsInStock))&$count=true&$top=1000)

I can't find the reason why the $apply is not working, since it was working previously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That service is an older implementation of WCF Services that is only partially compliant with OData v4 query syntax and as such does not support `$apply`.

> but works if (apply) used instead of ("$apply")

You will notice that although there is no error, the query is returning the same results as if you had not included the `$apply` query option at all.

Your query syntax should work on a properly compliant API though, for instance you can use the TripPin service:

*this query itself is not very useful, but it demonstrates the syntax*

https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/People?$apply=groupby((LastName))